# 5-pair UTP and Gigabit Ethernet

Tags: ethernet, gigabit-ethernet

My house has a 5 pair twisted pair copper wire running. The cable reads "Pony 0.6mm X 5 pairs." Currently, I have a 100TX switch and I'm getting a throughput of around 70mpbs.

I am considering upgrading to gigabit switches. Is there any way to figure out if it will connect at 1000base?

Can the testing be done with one gigabit PC and a gigabit router?

The pairs seem to have about 1 twist per cm. Does that make it closer to CAT 3 or 5?

Edit: I tried connecting using Gigabit equipment. I used one PC with a gigabit ethernet port and had a C9 Archer router connected at 700mpbs to a Surface Pro on the other end. Using Iperf, I'm getting speeds upto 340mbps. Does that mean the cable supports gigabit speeds?

Comment: 5 pairs? Haven't heard that one yet. Was it originally phone wiring or something like that?

Comment: @grawity Yes. It was for a PBX system but also designed to carry data. The house was built in 2010/11 so it's not really that old.

Answer (score 1):

You might have there the
[Pony 05 Pair PVC Voice Cable 3005](http://ponycables.com/product/05-pair-pvc-telephone-cable/) :

[image]

If it is indeed this cable,
you could get in contact with the company to find out the uses possible for it.
It's likely that each pair can be used separately.
With luck on your side, it may be able to do data transfer as Cat 5 Ethernet cable.

Comment: That indeed appears what has been used here. Thanks. I'm already using it for data transfer at 100mbps.